SharePoint Documents of Parent dataverse entity are not shown on Child entity
I have two entities, let's say Parent and Child with a 1:n relation between. The Parent entity has a SharePoint documents folder associated via the sharepointdocumentlocation entity. As a System Administrator I can see the documents on the form of the Parent entity and on the form of the child entity. But with only my custom role, I can see the documents only on the Parent form. On the Child form, instead of the document list I see the first Tab of my Parent form.
My custom role has these permissions:

Parent: Create/Read/Write/Append/Appent to (Organization)
Child: Create/Read/Write/Append/Appent to (Organization)
sharepointdocumentlocation: Read (Organization)

Which additional permissions do I need so I can see the documents also on the Child form?
